# Magento 2 Cannot redirect from admin controller to front end

Tags: redirect, magento2

I am trying to use this code to redirect to a frontend URL, but it always redirects to the admin dashboard. I searched for and tried a lot of demo code, but I can't get it to work. I assume all attributes were set correctly.

```
 $url= $this->_storeManager->getStore(1)->getUrl('storelocator/index/index');
 $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
 $resultRedirect->setUrl($url);
 return $resultRedirect;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102457/33058):

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $manStore,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->manStore = $manStore;
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    ...
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $route = 'customer/account'; // w/o leading '/'
    $store = $this->manStore->getStore();
    $url = $store->getUrl($route, [$parm => $value]); // second arg can be omitted 
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($url);
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution of getting storefront URL:

```
/* @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager */
/* @var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store */
$scopeResolver = $objectManager->create( 'Magento\Framework\Url\ScopeResolverInterface', [ 'areaCode' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area\Area::AREA_FRONTEND ] );
$url = $objectManager->create( 'Magento\Framework\Url', [ 'scopeResolver' => $scopeResolver ] )->setScope( $store )->getUrl( 'xxx/xxx/xxx', [ '_scope_to_url' => false, '_nosid' => true ] );
```

Comment: Don't use direct object manager calls as you're breaking DI concept.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue. Solution in my case was rather trivial. Adding slash at the beginning of the url did the trick.

```
    $result = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    // Pay attention to leading slash in url.
    $result->setUrl('/training_render/layout/onepage');
    return $result;
```

Thanks